# Codeigniter image resize library not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
for($i=0; $i< count($data['upload_data']); $i++){

                //resize uploade image
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $data['upload_data'][$i]['full_path'];
                $config['new_image'] = $data['upload_data'][$i]['full_path'];
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width']    = 700;
                $config['height']   = 700;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

                $this->image_lib->resize(); 
                $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

I want to resize the images in a loop, all the images are already in the database, but after running this script, only the first image is resized.

All the path are correct, anyone else encountering this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading image_lib you might need to initialize it.

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

See: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

> You will NOT need to use the $this->image_lib->initialize function if
>   you save your preferences in a config file.